# Insert into select sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I appreciate any clue or help

I have a database, containing a linked table and a split form , which has a checkbox on it. I would like to copy current record on the form (certain fields) to  the linked table, if checkbox is true.

I assigned this to on checkbox click event:

```
Private Sub CBor_Click()
Dim CBor As CheckBox
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim strInsert As String

If Me.CBor = False Then Exit Sub
Else: Set dbs = CurrentDb
  strInsert = "INSERT INTO EchoID(Room, [Date], PtName, MRN, Dx, CVT)" & _
       "SELECT Room, LogBookDate, PatientName, MRN, Diagnosis, StaffName FROM Logbook_tBL " & _
       "WHERE (((Logbook_tBL.LogBookID)=" & Me.txtLogBookID & "))"
    Debug.Print strInsert
   CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
End If
End Sub
```

It finally gave no error, but it sometimes works and sometimes does not. Since it gives off no error, i have no idea how to troubleshoot. Appreciate any hints.

Comment: Perhaps your checkbox can be Null? Try: `If Nz(Me!CBor.Value, False) = False Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: Hi, Mr Gustav.. Thank you for your response. I changed that line as you recommended but the code still does not work as intended.

Comment: We don't know how it fails, neither the intended outcome.